# Abstract Error while opening dataset

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-7

I am creating a `Tdataset` object in a function.
Please find the code below:

```
procedure CreateDataset;
var
  LDataset: TDataset;
begin
  LDataset := TDataset.create(nil);
  if LDataset = nil then
    Exit;
  with LDataset do
  begin
    FieldDefs.Clear;
    FieldDefs.Add('NAME', ftString, 50);
    FieldDefs.Add('Designation', ftString, 20);
    FieldDefs.Add('Address', ftString,100);
    FieldDefs.Add('ContactNum', ftString,12);
    Open; // giving exception as 'AbstractError' at this line
  end;
end;
```

I am getting an exception as **abstract error** while opening the dataset.
Please correct me if I am doing any mistake.

Comment: `TDataset` is an abstract class. Do not instantiate it.

Comment: Please read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EAbstractError and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Abstract_Methods

Comment: Also, `if LDataset = nil then Exit;` doesn't make sense. if the creation had failed, it would have thrown an exception, not return `nil`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for docs it helps a lot

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful thanks for corrcting me

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's see:

```
procedure CreateDataset;
var
  LDataset: TDataset;
begin
  LDataset := TDataset.create(nil);
    // ERROR. TDataset is an abstract class, don't instantiate it.
    // Use a descendant class instead.
  if LDataset = nil then
    Exit;
    // NONSENSE. It would never work. Maybe you're afraid about
    // 'dataset not created'. If so, the constructor will raise an
    // exception.
  with LDataset do
  begin
    FieldDefs.Clear;
      // FOR WHAT? You create this dataset a millisecond ago.
      // It's empty. 
    FieldDefs.Add('NAME', ftString, 50);
      // BTW, you should not create and fill components without
      // reason. Try to use design-time abilities instead.
    FieldDefs.Add('Designation', ftString, 20);
    FieldDefs.Add('Address', ftString,100);
    FieldDefs.Add('ContactNum', ftString,12);
    Open;
       // ERROR. Even if correct dataset class used, it will not
       // open if it is not linked to some correct connection object.
  end;
  // LEAK. And now? You created the dataset. You opened it. You
  // stored it nowhere. You do not return it. At the moment
  // you'll leave the procedure, the opened dataset would be
  // lost. It would never close and never be disposed until
  // the end of program.
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is just a sample code which I have added. BTW, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @AB It's fine to build fields at runtime. No compelling reason why you must do so at designtime.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's a critique. In this case, the example is probably far too abbreviated to be useful. If the properties WERE set up in the IDE, then it would be more likely to work because of all of the missing pieces in this example.